# How could I define the observation_space for my custom openai enviroment?

Tags: python, openai-gym

I'm currently working on a custom Gym environment that represents a networ graph (with nodes and links), and I am struggling to determine what the `observation_space` variable of my environment should look like. I don't plan on using a graphic representation of my environment (meaning that the `render()` method will only use the terminal).

I looked for answers on the openai gihub page, and I found this [issue](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/593). However, I still don't understand how should my `observation_space` variable should look like.

My gym environment is currently looking like [this](https://hastebin.com/aberenuwoc.rb).

TL;DR:

- the current state is in fact the node on which the agent is located
- the current state is a character
- the list of the possible states is explicited in the constructor

Moreover, I plan on using Q-learning algorithms for exploiting this graph: should I discretise the `observation_space`? I plan using a RL algorithm like [like this one](https://gist.github.com/gkhayes/3d154e0505e31d6367be22ed3da2e955#file-mountain_car-py).

How should I represent my `observation_space`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, I know this is way too late, but I'm having this very same problem, so I was just wondering if you solve this

Answer (score 1):

In a Gym environment, the observation space represents all the possible observations that can be returned by the step() method. I took a look at your environment code and for me, it looks like that your observation space is the list of nodes of your graph. In this case, you will have to extend the gym.spaces.Space class, since there's no "list" space in default Gym.

Comment: how would you do that in a way it is compatible with the standard learning algorithms (of for example stable baseline)?

Answer (score 1):

Your observation is just one discrete information: Which node. So you could use a discrete space which has one number for every possible node.
Could look something like this:

```
self.observation_space = spaces.Discrete(len(node_array))
```

It sounds like you need a mapping from numbers to characters but that shouldn't be hard.

I guess it get's more complicated if the number of nodes changes or you need a VecEnv with Envs of different node count. But it sounds like you know the node count and DQN doesn't use parallelized Envs as far as I remember. So should be OK.

The action space could be more problematic when not all nodes have the same degree of neighbors. In principle you have again just a discrete space. Each number for one path to take. But the amount of possible paths change and I don't know how to handle dynamic spaces using Gym Env and standard RL-Libs. A possible workaround could be an upper-bound for possible actions maybe combined with an array which masks impossible actions.